# SPF and DKIM pass, but DMARC fails for source_ip

Tags: email, spf, dmarc

I have configured our DMARC policy to quarantine and our domain SPF and DKIM are configured appropriately. The SPF record is as follows:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +include:sendgrid.net -all
```

However this is the report being returned:

```
<feedback>
    <report_metadata>
        <org_name>Yahoo! Inc.</org_name>
        <email>postmaster@dmarc.yahoo.com</email>
        <report_id>000</report_id>
        <date_range>
            <begin>000</begin>
            <end>000</end>
        </date_range>
    </report_metadata>
    <policy_published>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <adkim>r</adkim>
        <aspf>r</aspf>
        <p>quarantine</p>
        <pct>100</pct>
    </policy_published>
    <record>
        <row>
            <source_ip>167.89.81.220</source_ip>
            <count>1</count>
            <policy_evaluated>
                <disposition>quarantine</disposition>
                <dkim>fail</dkim>
                <spf>fail</spf>
            </policy_evaluated>
        </row>
        <identifiers>
            <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
        </identifiers>
        <auth_results>
            <dkim>
                <domain>sendgrid.net</domain>
                <result>pass</result>
            </dkim>
            <spf>
                <domain>sendgrid.net</domain>
                <result>pass</result>
            </spf>
        </auth_results>
    </record>
</feedback>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which is your A and MX record? (you reference them from the SPF record)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your messages are passing basic SPF and DKIM tests but are failing DMARC alignment (the SPF and DKIM tests pass, but the SPF and DKIM domains align with the sendgrid.net domain, not your domain). Please review the available Sendgrid documentation with regards to DMARC, SPF, and DKIM and ensure your domain authentication configuration is complete. Relevant documentation can be found here: 
[Everything about DMARC](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/dmarc/), [How to set up domain authentication](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/),
[SPF](https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/spf/),
[DKIM](https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/dkim/). These documents make reference to additional supporting information you may find helpful in understanding how DMARC leverages SPF and DKIM.